# emit code works bad

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I'm trying to create a call to a proxy method in generated class with opcodes and I get `ExecutionEngineException`. This method must receive return type as first argument and array of arguments from calling method.

```
var methodILGen = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
if (methodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(void))
{
 var method = typeBuilder.BaseType.GetMethod("proxyCaller");
 var args = methodInfo.GetParameters();
 var lb = methodILGen.DeclareLocal(methodInfo.ReturnType);  

 LocalBuilder _args = methodILGen.DeclareLocal(typeof(object[]));

 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, args.Length);
 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));
 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, _args);

 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, _args);
 for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
 {
  methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, i);      
  methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, i + 1);
  methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
  methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, _args);
 }
 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, _args);

 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // instance pointer
 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, lb.LocalType); //return type
 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, _args); //args list

 methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);//, new Type[0]);

 if (methodInfo.ReturnType.IsValueType || methodInfo.ReturnType.IsEnum) methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, lb.LocalType);
}
methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder, methodInfo);
```

And the second problem is that i receive firstly an array of args and then return type.

Comment: This is a bad title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Have you tried saving the assembly and running PEVerify on it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Save your dynamic assembly, and use PEVerify.exe to check it.
2. OpCodes.ldtoken does not put Type on stack. It puts RuntimeTypeHandle. To get type you should do something like that:

   ```
   var getTypeMethod = typeof (Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle");  
   methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, lb.LocalType);  
   methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getTypeMethod);  
   methodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, _args);
   ```